# Cassandra Java Driver get TypeCodec for Java type

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have the following method with generic parameter:

```
public <K> Store<K> createStore(final Class<K> keyType);
```

which will just create a table in cassandra with the given type for me.

I want to check whether there is already a default implementation of a `TypeCodec` for the given `keyType`. If yes then I just want to use this codec otherwise I'll use a generic codec written by myself.

Cassandra's `CodecRegistry` class provides the methods:

```
public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(DataType cqlType, Class<T> javaType);
public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(DataType cqlType);
public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(T value);
public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(DataType cqlType, TypeToken<T> javaType);
public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(DataType cqlType, T value);
```

The thing is, none of these methods fits for my use case. Almost all methods require `DatatType cqlType`parameter which I cannot provide because I did not find a way to map the my given `keyType` class literal to a possible matching Cassandra `Datatype`. (is this possible?)

The only one that comes close for what I want, is:
`public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(T value);`
but it requires an *instance* of the the class and not a class literal.
So what I want is:

`public <T> TypeCodec<T> codecFor(Class<T> javaType);`

which would give me just the default `TypeCodec` to use for the given type, i.e. if i pass in the type "java.lang.Integer" then the corresponding cassandra TypeCodec for Integers shoud be returned.

Any suggestions how to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you need has been already requested but not implemented, see [JAVA-1015](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1015). Please vote for this ticket and explain why you would like to have it implemented.

In the meanwhile, I would suggest you to redesign your `createStore` method; your application probably knows – or at least *should know* – what CQL type to use for a given `keyType`. Not knowing which CQL type to use is generally a bad smell.

Answer (score 0):

`CodecRegistry` class have two fields that store all `TypeCodec`

```
/**
 * List of Built in Codec
 */
private static final TypeCodec<?>[] BUILT_IN_CODECS;    

/**
 * The list of user-registered codecs.
 */
private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<TypeCodec<?>> codecs;
```

You can see that both are private. We can access them with java reflection

```
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE;

Map<Class, TypeCodec> javaTypeCodecMap = new HashMap<>();

try {
    Field field = codecRegistry.getClass().getDeclaredField("BUILT_IN_CODECS");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    TypeCodec<?>[] builtInCodecs = (TypeCodec<?>[]) field.get(codecRegistry);
    for (TypeCodec<?> typeCodec : builtInCodecs) {
        javaTypeCodecMap.put(typeCodec.getJavaType().getRawType(), typeCodec);
    }
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Field field = codecRegistry.getClass().getDeclaredField("codecs");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<TypeCodec<?>> codecs = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<TypeCodec<?>>) field.get(codecRegistry);
    for (TypeCodec<?> typeCodec : codecs) {
        javaTypeCodecMap.put(typeCodec.getJavaType().getRawType(), typeCodec);
    }
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//You have the map, now you can get TypeCodec from class name
System.out.println(javaTypeCodecMap.get(String.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work. I'm not sure whether I want to rely on reflection though. Do you see any other way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I have search through their api, don't find any other way. Actual they don't need one like that.

Comment: Or you could just hard coded a map, for all the typecodec